# How to Subtract Time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I'm new to Ruby and Rails.
I have a time type column in the db which stores user time inputs from form.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <%= form_for(Gotime.new) do |f| %>
    <%= f.time_select :hours%>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I need to subtract X minutes from `Gotime.last` to get new time. It seems that in order to do it I need to somehow set `Gotime` to the starting time from which I will count Х minutes back. How can I do this? Is this idea correct or this should be done some other way?

Comment: What is `Gotime` and `Gotime.last`?

Comment: The general way to subtract x time is `Gotime.last - 3.minutes`

Comment: Gotime is my table created with "rails g model Gotime hours:time minutes:time", Gotime.last is the latest time inputted by the user into the form that is in the "hours" column.

Comment: if i write <%= newtime = Sleep.last - 3.minutes %> I get an error: NoMethodError in Gotimes#new undefined method `-' for #<Gotime:0x007f97565fb820>

Comment: This error occur because you subtracting `object` with time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `time` column

> Gotime.last.time - 3.minutes

If you have `hours` and `minutes` column
and you want to subtract time by minutes :

```
obj = Gotime.last

time = DateTime.now.change({ hour: obj.hours, min: obj.minutes, sec: 0 })

time - 3.minutes
```

If you have date time you can replace `DateTime.now` with it